# How to set different page orientation per page in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I wanted to have portrait for page 1 and landscape for page 2. How could I achieve that in QGIS Print Composer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot mix portrait and landscape in the same print composer composition. You have to have two different print composers.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the above answer. It ended my search. So to have both layouts in the same document, what I did was, I rotated all items in the page that I wanted to be portrait using Item properties -> Rotation -> I rotated all to 270, then saved the file to PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider to make use of atlas feature and then control page orientation by an attribute value of the atlas control featureclass?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't use atlas feature because, the Print Composer itself is used by another plugin that relies on composer.

Comment: Pity that Atlas wasn't available to you - you can set pretty much everything based on the Atlas (e.g., setting orientation by `case when  bounds_width(   @atlas_geometry  ) > bounds_height(   @atlas_geometry  ) then 'landscape' else 'portrait' end`). Can't change the number of legend columns that way - so I use two Legends (3-column for L, and 1-column for P), and toggle visibility and rendering based on `@atlas_geometry` h vs w. All other components can be changed for each Atlas item using `@atlas_geometry` expressions to set their position, size, rendering, etc.